# jQuery how to refer to the directory $.post()

Tags: php, jquery

welcome 
how to file script.js refer to index.php?

in script.js:

```
$.post('../php/index.php', {data});
```

structure directory:

```
js/
  script.js
php/
  index.php
index.html
```

return me in console:

> 404 (Not Found) Cannot POST /php/index.php

Comment: The $.post call will be from the index.html location. So update the script.js to: `$.post('php/index.php', {data});`

Comment: thanks @daveyWavey it's working

Answer (score 0):

Just use the file location in full, like:

```
$.post('http://www.example.com/directory/php/index.php', {data});
```

Comment: that means you'll need to update all your js if you move to a different domain, though

Comment: Yeah, but it still a good approach considering the fact that the js files can also be moved :)

Comment: I get around by having a variable called `site` in the HEAD section of all pages (e.g. `var site = "http://www.example.com";`, and any references to the FQDN then use this. site is added to the page by PHP & reflects the current URL, so if the site moves, the value gets updated automatically

Answer (score 0):

The url in your javascript has to be relative to the current active url in the web browser. The best way to solve this for you is to use a absolute path. Like this:

```
$.post('/php/index.php', {data});
```